# speed up writing to mongoDB with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am working on an API for data from a weather model - not anything that will run in production.
I use MongoDB to hold the data. The data are gridded with dimension `[Time: X, Latitude: 1100, Longitude 1200]`, so for one time (X=1), there are ~1.3 million gridpoints.

Querying a specific location is okay with respect to response-time. The problem is writing to MongoDB which is terribly slow (+5 minutes for 1.3 million points on a reasonable laptop).

I have three indexes:

- regular unique index on "_id"
- geospatial location_2dsphere
- regular index on "timestamp"

Another thing to consider is that data is updated every 10-60 minutes, where afterwards the old data can be dropped. I use pymongo to create the collection and indexes as follows

```py
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://weathermongo:27017')
nwp_database = client['nwp_db']
    
nwp_database.create_collection("my_collection")
        
col = nwp_database.my_collection
col.create_index([("location",GEOSPHERE)]) # 2dsphere index for geospatial queries
col.create_index([ ("timestamp", 1) ])
```

Then I write to the database as follows:

```py
my_collection = client['nwp_db'].my_collection

for tdeks in nwp_time:

    geojson = []
    for i in range(len(latitude)):
        geojson.append({
                "timestamp": tdeks,
                "pointid": int(i),
                "location": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        round(longitude[i],4),
                        round(latitude[i],4)
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "temperature": round(t2m[i],1),
                        "precipitation": round(tp[i],1)
                    }
                }
            })

        k+=1

    my_collection.insert_many(geojson, ordered=False)
```

I have tried timing different sections and from that, I see that everything goes relatively fast until it reaches the call to the `insert_many` function [from pymongo](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html). I tried to set `ordered=False` as shown, but that only made the writing a little faster.
I am out of ideas on how to solve this issue, and since I am not an expert in databases at all I wonder if MongoDB is even the right choice for this. At some point, I would like to also add vertical levels as an extra dimension, which is why I thought MongoDB seemed like a fair choice.
Any suggestions to improve the writing efficiency or other solutions are much welcome.

For completeness I also show how I query my data below (which works fine):

```py
import pymongo
import datetime as dt

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://weathermongo:27017')

filter={
        'location': {
            '$near': {
                '$geometry': {
                    'type': 'Point', 
                    'coordinates': [
                        float(longitude), float(latitude)
                    ]
                }, 
                '$maxDistance': 3000
            }
        }, 
        'timestamp': {
            '$gte': dt.datetime(2021, 2, 11, 8, 30, 0, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc), 
            '$lt': dt.datetime(2021, 2, 11, 12, 30, 0, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc)
        }
    }

sort=list({
    'pointid': 1, 
    'ts': 1
}.items())
    
limit=100

cursor = client['nwp_db']['my_collection'].find(
         filter=filter,
         sort=sort,
         limit=limit)
```

Comment: How large is the `nwp_time` array?

Comment: The mongod log should report any operations that are slow, modern  version of MongoDB will also report time spent waiting on disk and locks.  You should be able to examine system metrics, timestamps and other data in the logs, and timestamps from the application to work out where the bottleneck is.